# playsms custom gateway bug

Tags: php, sms, gateways

Trying to make a new sms gateway for playsms 0.9.9.2 called "aft". Whenever I include the custom gateway files in the gateways folder, no gateway works; they all fail with a log like this:

```
L2 sendsms # start uid: sender:000
L2 sendsms_queue_create # saving queue_code:627327099f4dec15197ed24c124b1ca2 src:000
L2 sendsms_queue_create # saved queue_code:627327099f4dec15197ed24c124b1ca2 id:2
L2 sendsms_queue_push # saving queue_code:627327099f4dec15197ed24c124b1ca2 dst:+25*********
L2 sendsms_queue_push # saved queue_code:627327099f4dec15197ed24c124b1ca2 smslog_id:2
L2 sendsms # end queue_code:627327099f4dec15197ed24c124b1ca2 sms_count:1
L2 sendsmsd # start processing queue_code:627327099f4dec15197ed24c124b1ca2 sms_count:1 uid:0 gpid:0 sender_id:000
L2 sendsmsd # sending queue_code:627327099f4dec15197ed24c124b1ca2 smslog_id:2 to:+25******** sms_count:1 counter:1
L2 sendsms_process # start
L2 sendsms_process # end with fail not enough credit smslog_id:2
L2 sendsmsd # result queue_code:627327099f4dec15197ed24c124b1ca2 to:+25******** flag:1 smslog_id:2
L2 sendsmsd # finish processing queue_code:627327099f4dec15197ed24c124b1ca2 uid:0 sender_id:000 sms_count:1
```

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your log includes log level, function name, and log message. The only error I see in your log report has happened in 'sendsms_process' function. Look at the like which says:

```
L2 sendsms_process # end with fail not enough credit smslog_id:2
```

You need to check if rating is defined correctly and if your user has enough credit.

Messages will be rated based on destination if a rate is defined for the destination in "Manage SMS rate" page. Otherwise, 'Default SMS rate' will be used to rate outgoing messages. 'Default SMS rate' is configurable in 'Main configuration' page.

Also, each user has a credit balance in playsms. Check 'Manage User' page and make sure your user has enough credit balance.